# When and how do we use the formula Power = force X velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity, power

I'm unable to understand the solution given in this book mine... Why are we adding the resistive force? In fact, i would really appreciate if someone explains the question to me, I'm really struggling with the understanding of the formula  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GP9G.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Unfortunately, this question is off-topic. We don't usually explain single textbook questions because such posts aren't useful to a broader set of readers. We prefer conceptual questions, and it seems you almost have one! It'd be great if you could remove the parts referring to that particular image and ask a general question about considering the opposing force while computing power.

Comment: You may want to look at [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Answer (score 1):

The question is about the total power the car (engine) has to develop during acceleration.

Part of this power will be spent to accelerate the car (the corresponding force is $ma$) and part of the power will be spent overcoming the resistance due to friction and drag (the corresponding force is given as the total resistive force).